# C++ constructor with declaration account(int =0);

Tags: c++

```
class Act {

protected:

    string Owner;

    double Balance;
public:
    explicit Act(int = 0);

    double getBalance() { return Balance; };
};
```

What is the meaning of line of constructor Act(int =0);  Need what int=0 would do here.

Comment: It's a default value. If you don't pass a value to the constructor, it will receive the value `0`.

Comment: it makes the first argument of a type `int` have default value of `0`. Thus, you can create `Act object` without specyfing the value of parameter

Comment: I only name the declaration parameter if it would help document the parameter.  If it were `explicit Act(Owner const&);` I wouldn't put in the "dummy" parameter name, but if it were `explicit Act(string const& owner);` I would.

Comment: It is an ordinary function parameter declaration (with default argument), in which the parameter name is omitted. You can replace it with `explicit Act(int i = 0);` and it won't affect anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation**

```
explicit Act (int = 0);
```

defines a constructor, that construct an `Act` from an `int` parameter.  The `=0` means that if the parameter can be omitted, it will have a default value of 0.  The `explicit` keyword tells the compiler not to use this constructor for making an implicit conversion.

**Examples of use**

As it is:

```
Act a1;           // Will generate the same code as Act a1(0);
Act a5{};         // Same as above, but using the braced initialization 
Act a2(12);       // Obvious 
Act a3=13;        // Ouch ! Compiler error because of explicit 
Act a4 = Act(13); // Ok, because now the call is explicit
```

If you wouldn't have the explicit keyword, then this line would be ok

```
Act a3=13;        // If not explicit, this is the same than Act a3=Act(13);
```

**Important remarks**

The default value is not something that is part of the constructor itself, but a behavior that is defined on the caller side, based on the declaration of the constructor known by the caller.

This means that you could include declare the class with different default values in different compilation units.  Although strange, this is perfectly valid.

Note that the absence of parameter name in the declaration is not a problem either, because, the parameter name can be declared within the constructor definition:

```
Act::Act(int x) : Balance((double)x) {
    cout <<"Constructor Act with parameter "<<x<<endl;
}
```

Finally, note that if you want to use the default value by omitting the parameter, but that your constructor has only one parameter, you should either use the syntax form a1 or a5 in the examples above.  You should however not use the syntax with empty parentheses because this would be understood as a function declaration:

```
Act a0();   // Ouch !! function declaration ! Use a0 or a0{} instead.
```

Comment: `Act a3 = 13` is not equivalent to `Act a3 = Act(13)`.    For a non-explicit constructor, it is equivalent (just alternate syntax) to `Act a3(13)`.

Comment: @Peter Standard says in 17.6.2 "*The [conversion] function selected is called with the initializer expression as its argument; if the function is a constructor, the call **initializes a temporary** of the cv-unqualified version of the destination type. The temporary is a prvalue. The result of the call (which is the temporary for the constructor case) **is then used to direct-initialize**, according to the rules above, the object that is the destination of the copy-initialization*".  I understand this as `Act a3(Act(13))` which is the same as  `Act a3=Act(13)`.

Comment: @Peter The standard continues by reminiding the copy elision that CAN take place:  "*In certain cases, an implementation is permitted to eliminate the copying inherent in this direct-initialization **by constructing the intermediate result directly into** the object being initialized;*"  - This rule transforms `Act a3(Act(13))` into `Act a3(13)`.  So in the end the result is the same.  I just applied the rules without the short-cut of the copy elision.

Comment: @Peter additional infos on https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/ for case (f).  Note that A a=x is teh same as A a(x) only if x is already of type a (copy construction).  -  Sorry for the repeated messages, but the max length of comments was simply too short for the detailed explanation :-)

Comment: Since C++17 , all three forms have the same semantics (the only difference is that `explicit` prevents one of them from compiling). There is no longer a temporary involved in any case

Answer (score 0):

In order to address your question we must break down what the line does.

The line calls the constructor for the class `Act`, the int which has no variable name requires the constructor to take an int. However the `=0` part is the default parameter telling the constructor that you don't need the int just place a 0 there.